# Xamarin's Dynamic Resources Not Working In Items Source

Tags: xamarin, dynamic, resources, itemssource

I am new to Xamarin. I try to understand Dynamic Resources, and come out with a very simple project.
I have created 3 Dynamic resources of type String in App.xaml, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyMobileApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:String x:Key="LangAbout">A</x:String>
            <x:String x:Key="LangProfile">P</x:String>
            <x:String x:Key="LangSettings">S</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is my MenuPageTest.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage Title="Menu"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyMobileApp.Views.MenuPageTest">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><ViewCell><Grid Padding="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="20"/>
            </Grid></ViewCell></DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsSource><x:Array Type="{x:Type TextCell}">
                <TextCell Text="{DynamicResource LangProfile}"  Detail="0"/>
                <TextCell Text="{DynamicResource LangSettings}" Detail="8"/>
                <TextCell Text="{DynamicResource LangAbout}"    Detail="9"/>
            </x:Array></ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="Change Resources" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is my code-behind, MenuPageTest.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyMobileApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MenuPageTest : ContentPage
    {
        public MenuPageTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Resources["LangAbout"] = "About";
            Resources["LangProfile"] = "Profile";
            Resources["LangSettings"] = "Settings";
        }
    }
}
```

When I first run it, the list shows 3 items correctly, "P", "S" and "A".
When I press the button, I expect the 3 items to be updated to "Profile", "Settings" and "About", but nothing is changed.

In fact, I step into the codes, and find that the resources have indeed changed, but the change is not reflected onto the items in the list view.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tested it and got the same result as you,  Application. The Resources more lik StaticResource，It will only be assigned once and any changes to resource dictionary ignored

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, have been travelling a bit. Thanks for helping out. My last resort, is to update each and every element in the list, by assigning them using SetDynamicResource method again, and it seems to work. This hack seems crude, but at least it doesn't trigger any events of the list.